# Compiling Cx-Freeze under Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, executable, cx-freeze

For the entire day I have been attempting to compile cx-Freeze under Ubuntu 14.04 and had no luck. So I gave up and decided to ask experts here.

**What I have**

1. Ubuntu 14.04
2. Python 3.4
3. python-dev, python3-dev, python3.4-dev installed (I know this common issue)
4. Sources of cx-Freeze 4.3.3

I tried two ways:

1. install from the sources
2. install by pip

**Install from the sources**

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

**What I got**

a lot of

```
MyPath/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/source/bases/Console.c:24: undefined reference to `PyErr_Print'
MyPath/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/source/bases/Console.c:24: undefined reference to `Py_FatalError'
```

and then

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

**Install by pip**

```
sudo pip3 install cx-Freeze
```

**What I got**

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/cx-Freeze/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-c954v7x6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cx-Freeze
Storing debug log for failure in /home/grimel/.pip/pip.log
```

and in pip.log

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/cx-Freeze/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-c954v7x6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cx-Freeze
```

So, I expect you to help me with this issue and gonna be very thankful:)

Comment: Any particular reason for not using a [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/cx-freeze)?

Comment: Maybe I'm a geek. Who knows?

Comment: If you look at the page I linked to above, you can find the required packages, and the diff they had to apply to get it to compile. That might help.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304), related to something Debian/Ubuntu change in distutils. That issue link has a workaround.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In **setup.py** string

```
if not vars.get("Py_ENABLE_SHARED", 0):
```

replace by

```
if True:
```

---

Thanks to **Thomas K**

Comment: I cannot find the 
if not vars.get("Py_ENABLE_SHARED", 0):
statement in setup.py file

Answer (score 6):

From [cx_freeze/issues](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304)

## Download

You need to [download the source code](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=cx_Freeze&version=4.3.4)

## For python 3.3 and 3.4:

1. `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
3. Open setup.py and change the line

   `if not vars.get("Py_ENABLE_SHARED", 0):`

   to

   `if True:`
4. `python3 setup.py build`
5. `sudo python3 setup.py install`

## For python 2.7:

1. `sudo apt-get install python-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
3. Open setup.py and change the line

   `if not vars.get("Py_ENABLE_SHARED", 0):`

   to

   `if True:`
4. `python setup.py build`
5. `sudo python setup.py install`

Answer (score 4):

GriMel's answer worked for me.  Until cx_freeze releases an update for this, I'm including a set of steps that you can do to get this working using GriMels' solution.

```
# create and activate virtualenv (as desired)
virtualenv envs/test_cxfreeze
. ./envs/test_cxfreeze/bin/activate

# download cxfreeze; do not install yet 
mkdir src/ 
pip install --download=./src/ cx-freeze
tar zxvf ./src/cx_Freeze-4.3.4.tar.gz -C ./src/

# fix bug in setup.py
vim src/cx_Freeze-4.3.4/setup.py
84c84
<             if True:
---
>             if not vars.get("Py_ENABLE_SHARED", 0):

# install cxfreeze
pip install ./src/cx_Freeze-4.3.4/
```

I've also opened up a bitbucket issue with what appears to be the source repo.

```
https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/153/cx_freeze-434-compile-error-on-ubuntu-1404
```

Comment: after following your instructions, it will install, but trying to freeze a small hello world script (that works with cx freeze on python2 fails), im using ubuntu 12.04 though, cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Console

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you might have a typo 
change

```
 sudo pip3 install cx-Freeze
```

to

```
 sudo pip3 install cx_Freeze
```

Comment: `cx-Freeze`  and `cx_Freeze` is the same thing here.

Comment: install --record /tmp/pip-nr20fmvl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8b_mhb24/cx-Freeze/